# Guid? value ToString("N") not working

Tags: c#, guid

If I try to convert a nullable GUID ToString(), it works nicely but I try to remove the "hyphens" from the GUID by `myGuid.ToString("N")` I get an IntelliSense error that reads: "No overload for method ToString method takes one arguments".

However, if I try to convert a regular (non-nullable) GUID to string with N formatter, it works fine.

Any idea how to make it work?

```
public void DoSomething(Guid regularGuid, Guid? nullableGuid)
{
   if(nullableGuid != null)
   {
      var string1 = regularGuid.ToString("N"); // This works
      var string2 = nullableGuid.ToString(); // This works also
      var string3 = nullableGuid.ToString("N"); // This does NOT work
   }
}
```

Comment: Is it a compiler error, or warning? (Does it still build?)

Comment: `nullableGuid.Value.ToString("N");`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Guid?` is actually `Nullable<T>`, which does not provide an overload for `.ToString(string)`. It only provides the parameterless overload that every object has.

You can get what you want by using

```
var string4 = nullableGuid.Value.ToString("N");
```

This is guaranteed to work as you previously checked that nullableGuid is non-null.

Using C# 6 you could also write

```
var string4 = nullableGuid?.Value.ToString("N");
```

without the need for the separate null check.